# Initializer must be a compile time constant

Tags: dart

I just want have a final List with colors :

```dart
final List<String> COLORS =  ['#cefbe4', '#81ec72', '#5cd646'];
final num MAX = 90;
class Square {
 // ...
```

It's ok for MAX but it does not compile for list :
Initializer must be a compile time constant

I also tried :

```dart
static final num MAX = 90;
class Square {
    final List<String> COLORS =  ['#cefbe4', '#81ec72', '#5cd646'];
```

New error : "initializer must be a compile time constant"

The only solution, I found is to initialise in constructor...
I don't like this solution : I don't want a list instance by Square object.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get the same errors as you. In the first case I get a compile time warning "Expected constant expression" and in the second case another compile-time warning and a runtime error. Try the latest SDK which you can find [here](http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/).

```dart
static final num MAX = 90;
class Square {
    final List<String> COLORS =  ['#cefbe4', '#81ec72', '#5cd646'];
```

In this case static it doesn't make any sense because **static** denotes *class variables* which are the same for all instantiated objects of the same class. And in this case **MAX** is outside a class boundary. Hence a runtime error is shown and a compile time warning ("Top-level field cannot be static").

I guess both **MAX** and **COLORS** are supposed to be the same for all instances of the *Square* class. So it makes sense to do this:

```dart
class Square {
    static final List<String> COLORS = const ['#cefbe4', '#81ec72', '#5cd646'];
    static final num MAX = 90;
}
```

Comment: True, I was using the build of last week (I wasn't notified by this version expire).
Now with const, it work fine !!
Thanks

Comment: Note that this will change in the future; actually, it was already changed in the specification. The original code is perfectly OK according to the spec, we're just waiting for the implementations to catch up. You will be able to initialize static/top-level variables with an arbitrary expression that will be evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 0):

The list itself is the part that is final, not the contents.  The contents inside a final list can still be added and removed.

```dart
final List<String> COLOURS = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This would create your list.  The actual filling of the list would be done in the constructor, or for that matter anywhere in your code.

It would be more appropriate to use an enum for this in my opinion.

Comment: I actually just noticed this isn't a Java question, but im sure the principle still stands.

Comment: No, the principle is not the same. Dart requires initialized variables to be *constant expressions* whereas *new ArrayList<String>()* creates a new object during the initialization process whose content is mutable.

Comment: Ah ok, as I said, I don't know Dart.